# In TextMate, is it possible to create a new file within a project window, without having to save it first?

Tags: textmate

I have recently switched from my beloved BBEdit to TextMate because of the amazing set of features TextMate's bundles provide.

However, in BBEdit I was able to create a new file within a project window without having to save it first, while TextMate forces me to save the file before going any further. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, confused, create a file without saving the file or create a file without saving the project?

Comment: Create a file without saving the file. The project is already saved.

Answer (score 0):

you can go from the menu with "File/New from template" this will create an Untitled file to the specified template that is not saved. However it is not in the project/project window that you currently have open. But if you think about it that is correct as if the file has not been saved TM would not know where to place it till you save it.

Answer (score 0):

With Textmate 2, you can use **File -> New Tab** (option + command + N).

Answer (score 0):

Really saving it is the only way.

To save a file in the specific directory tree:

- click on the directory you want the new file to be in
- press <kbd>Option+Command+N</kbd>
- now you can <kbd>Command+S</kbd>

It will have that directory path.